# REST Service throwing exception when passed a JSON array. What is my mistake?

Tags: java, json, rest, client, ibm-rad

I got to call a restful service owned by a thrid party. They are expecting a specific entry as array. I checked some questions here and wrote code to create the array of just 1 element. Even after that the service is complaining about the same issue. If I don't pass that array it responds correctly. But not the expected response. Say it recommends me something. I expect approved. I get back investigate if i don't pass the array. If I pass the array i am getting back exception where as i am expecting "approved"

```
{
"orgCode": "XXX",
"modelCode": "XXX",
"event": {
"contacts": [
    {
        "name": "XXX",
        "@id": "941689716",
        "company": "XXX"
    }
    ],.............................
```

So. I tried 2 ways and both are throwing the same exception

Method 1:  Create JSON Array and populate it directly

```
   JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
    info.put("@id", "941689716");
    info.put("name", "XXX");
    info.put("company", "XX");
    JSONArray contactsArray = new JSONArray();
    contactsArray.add(info);
    event.put("contacts", contactsArray.toString());
```

Method 2:  Create arraylist, add it to JSON Array

```
   JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
    info.put("@id", "941689716");
    info.put("name", "XXX");
    info.put("company", "XX");
    List<JSONObject> objects = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    objects.add(info);
    JSONArray contactsArray = new JSONArray();
    contactsArray.addAll(objects);
    event.put("contacts", contactsArray.toString());
```

The reason i tried method 2 was because, in the exception I see that they are expecting arraylist

```
Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@52d91fcc; line: 1, column: 50] (through reference chain: com.xx.xx.xx.xx[\"event\"]->com.xx.xx.xx.Event[\"contacts\"])"})
```

I am using java 6 on IBM RAD and the JSON objects are from com.ibm.json.java package. I cannot use any open source code due to regulations

So here is my question

Please correct me if i am wrong

Or

Can this be a server side issue? I read in another thread that if the arraylist has just 1 element they got to handle it, otherwise it might throw this error.

Comment: Your service is expecting a JSON object. You are sending it a JSON array.

Comment: I don't have big experience coding JSON. How do i correct this. Please help!!

Comment: Can you post a link to the documentation of the REST service you're calling, along with the complete exception you get?

Comment: Sorry. I am not allowed to do that. its not a free service.its licensed content.

Comment: @spirulence- +1 that you tried to help me out

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank [Sotirios-delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis). His comment made me to remove the .toString() at the end of the array while setting it in the root JSON object and hey!!!!! that worked and I got approved response back.